# Python 3.2 : urllib, SSL and TOR through socket : error with fileno function

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, urllib, tor

I have an error, when trying to connect in https over socksipy with the below code.

I followed the example here : [using tor as a SOCKS5 proxy with python urllib2 or mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449974/using-tor-as-a-socks5-proxy-with-python-urllib2-or-mechanize)

Or this one : [Python urllib over TOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148589/python-urllib-over-tor)

Edit : this code is actually working when I am using HTTP, but not with HTTPS

I have imported socks from the Socksipy python module.

### **Here is the code :**

```
import socks
import socket

#This function has no DNS resolve 
#it need to use the real ip adress to connect instead of www.google.fr
def create_connection_fixed_dns_leak(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

# MUST BE SET BEFORE IMPORTING URLLIB
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection_fixed_dns_leak

# END MUST BE SET BEFORE IMPORTING URLLIB
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

def getURL(pUrl, headers = {}, pNbMaxRetry = 12):       
    req = urllib.request.Request( pUrl )
    for headerKey, headerValue in headers:
        req.add_header( headerKey, headerValue )

    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    return resp
```

**Calling method :**

```
googleAdr = "https://173.194.65.94"
pageSocket = getURL( googleAdr )
pageHtml = pageSocket.read()
pageSocket.close()
page = BeautifulSoup( pageHtml )
print(" Page calendar :" + page .prettify() )
```

### **Here is the error :**

```
File "/home/turf/connectSafe.py", line 101, in getURL
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 139, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 370, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 388, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 348, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1176, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/urllib/request.py", line 1140, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 970, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 966, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 749, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/client.py", line 1111, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 189, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
    fileno=sock.fileno()
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fileno'
```

Have you any ideas ? even bad ones ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: can you show what modules you have imported? what is that `socks` (isn't defined)

Comment: I have edited the code in the question. The socks library is from Socksipy module of python

Comment: think it works only for HTTP proxy.
take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136916/using-socksipy-with-ssl), think you can try wrapping it with `ssl`. Of course you need to adjust your function to cater HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: Is there a way to h@ck the ssl file, module, by adding the missing function fileno ? I've tried but i don't know how with what I should fill this function.

Comment: any luck if wrapping the connection with `ssl`? I tested with python2.7 and it works

Comment: Can you explain or show me what you mean by wrapping the connection please ?

Comment: Have you read the link I posted on previous comment?
if you `import ssl`, and place `sslsock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)` and `return sslsock`

Comment: I'm curently trying it, I will notice you as soon as it's finished (or I soon as i'm stuck ;) )